# Mobile to Normal website Redirect

Tags: javascript, mobile, redirect

I have a CV/Resume site and when a user visits my website and the screen resolution is lower than 960 I redirect him to my mobile site through this JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">if (screen.width <= 960) {document.location = mobile.html";}</script>
```

My question is if the user wants to visit the normal site and hit a link the javascript will run again and it will redirect the user back to the mobile site. One method to solve this problem it could be to duplicate the normal site lets say index.html and index1.html one with the above code and one with no JS but i think this solution is so noobish. Any way to solve this problem? Before you answer please note that i have no access to the .htaccess file.

My problem is when a user visits my site with scree width lower than 960 go to mobile site but if he wants to see the full site press a link and get redirected to the full site no matter the screen width.

Comment: when the user hits the "normal" site, check if some cookie exists, if so, don't redirect, on the mobile website, when the user wants to be redirected to the "normal" site, create a cookie before redirecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a small code snippet. When the user changes from mobile to normal, run the following code:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setHours(expires.getHours + 24); 

document.cookie = (document.cookie ? document.cookie + ' ;' : '')
     + ' disableMobile=1; expires=' + expires.toGMTString();
```

and then change your redirect condition to

```
   if (screen.width <= 960 && document.cookie.indexOf('disableMobile') < 0) [...]
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways come to mind:

1. Use a cookie, so that the user's preference to stay on the full site will be remembered. Create/set the cookie just before redirecting.
2. Use a query parameter, `<a href="index.html?fullsite=true">Full site</a>` (or similar), which you set only in the link from `mobile.html` back to the normal site.

Then add a condition to your existing screen width test so that it only runs if the cookie/query parameter is not set.

(You may also like to add an extra link on your main index page to let the user choose the mobile version. Obviously if you go the cookie route this should clear the cookie.)

Comment: I think i will go with the second will i have to use php or it is possible with js and if it is posible with js can you link me to an example?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well the link on the mobile page will be just like in my answer. On your main index page you can use PHP to test for that request parameter or you can use JS to test the [window.location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to see if it contains that parameter. Sorry, I'm writing this from my phone so it's hard to write proper code but there should be enough info on the MDN page I linked to in the previous sentence.